# find_path in Cmake doesn't work with simple example,

Tags: cmake

I try to locate a document "netcdf.inc" in "/usr/local/include". I have tried PATHS, HINTS. Both of them don't work. In /usr/local/include exists netcdf.inc. Could someone help me? I will be very appreciative.

Best regards

```cmake
set(netcdf_inc_names "netcdf.inc")
if (NetCDF_INCLUDE_DIRS)
        
    message("it should be here")

    if (EXISTS "${NetCDF_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

        find_path(cdf_test_include_path
            NAMES ${netcdf_inc_names}
            PATHS /usr/local/
            PATH_SUFFIXES include
            NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

        message("${cdf_test_include_path}")

        if(NOT cdf_test_include_path)
            message(SEND_ERROR "Can not locate ${netcdf_inc_names} in ${NetCDF_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
        endif()
        #...
```

Output:

```
it should be here
cdf_test_include_path-NOTFOUND
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:145 (message):
   Can not locate netcdf.inc in /usr/local/include
```

Comment: The **absolute path** of your file is `/usr/local/include/netcdf.inc`, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The absolute Path is /usr/local/include/netcdf.inc

Comment: Just tested - your `find_path` call works for me (Linux, CMake 3.16). Resulted path is `/usr/local/include`. Probably, you misspell your file somehow. Try `ls /usr/local/include/netcdf.inc` in the command line.

Comment: ls /usr/local/include/netcdf.inc works well. I can't really understand, where is the problem. I have checked the path many times.